# How Can Convert DataRow to DataRowView in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dataview, datarowview

Can or how to convert DataRow to DataRowView?

For example:

```
   DataTable dt=ds.Tables[0];
   DataRow dr= dt.NewRow();           
   DataRowView drv = ????
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use

```
DataTable dt=ds.Tables[0];
DataRow dr= dt.NewRow();         
DataRowView drv= dt.DefaultView[dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr)];
```

Comment: You must remember that if the default view has been filtered the indexes may not line up. Similar solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989851/2122718

Answer (score 2):

The above method does not work if the DataRow status is Detached.
This code snippet could be used in such case:

```
        DataRow dRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        //...
        DataRowView dRowView = dRow.Table.DefaultView.AddNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < dRow.ItemArray.Length; i++)
        {
            dRowView.Row[i] = dRow[i];
        }
```

Comment: dear @Subramani, Thank you for your help, and please if this question is useful set up vote

Answer (score 2):

```
DataRowView selecRow = dataTable.DefaultView.Cast<DataRowView>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Row == desRow);
```

works, this is a litte shorter without "where" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use. 
It also works if the DataGrid is ordered.

```
DataRowView selecRow = dataTable.DefaultView.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(a => a.Row == desRow).FirstOrDefault();
```