# Row index's of row belongs to a DataTable along with Sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I would like to add one more query to this.. [How Can Convert DataRow to DataRowView in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632036/how-can-convert-datarow-to-datarowview-in-c-sharp)

```
DataRowView drv= dt.DefaultView[dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr)];
```

This is the code which is mentioned there..

Assume a scenario, that a column has sorted and if i try to get the row view based on the row index, it will mismatch..

How could overcome this?

Comment: I am not sure that the code from mentioned post is correct. You can't refer to row in datatabe before you add it. `NewRow` doesn't add the row to the table.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: That's doesnt needed.. i have removed that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use the `FindRows` method to get the matched rows..

```
DataRowView drv = dt.DefaultView.FindRows(dr[Regex.Match(dt.DefaultView.Sort, @"\[([^)]*)\]").Groups[1].Value])[0];
```

In my case, i could take the first value of `RowView` collection. This is a kind of filtering the dataview with the respective value... and it solves my problem...